# What does Minecraft's scary music mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Apparently it means there is a dungeon around but I can never find any?

If it does mean dungeons how far away will it trigger?

Comment: I wish I could hear the music :(

Comment: Do you not have speakers or does it not play? You can download the sounds [here](http://www.worldofminecraft.com/node/9216)

Comment: I hate those sounds. They always freak me out...

Comment: ITS HEROBRINE! AHHHHHH!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As described in [this article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience) on [minecraftwiki.net](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/),

> **Ambience** (sometimes called cave
> noises) is a set of sounds that
> occasionally plays when the player is
> in close proximity to an unlit [cave](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cavern).
> Despite their name, they are not
> sounds that one would expect to hear
> inside of a cave, such as falling
> pebbles, but rather supernatural
> noises frequently likened to ghostly
> train whistles, rice rockets, and
> demon roars.
>
> Ambient sounds require that a space at
> least 3×3×3, entirely at [light](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light) level
> zero, be positioned ten to twenty
> blocks away from the player in any
> direction. The space does not need to
> be sealed off - a sound can even play
> from a space that the player can
> actually see - nor does the player
> need to be underground to hear it. The
> sounds can also come from
> player-created spaces, even if that
> space is a box above the clouds.
>
> Contrary to popular insistence,
> ambience is **not** an indicator of nearby
> [ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ore), [dungeons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon), or [mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs#Agressive_Mobs). Following them
> can still lead the player to such
> things indirectly, since they emanate
> from unexplored caves.

Comment: to answer number 1 it is pressing f3 and looking around u can tell if there is a dungeon bacuase it well list enemies and others mobs by a some random number with letters in it if there is a large group of numbers and letters then theres your dungeon but if they didnt fix it yet by spamming your fog toggle key u can see light and flames and lava through stone and any other matieral u are trying to peer through

Comment: @overkillfish I think that's been fixed recently.

Comment: The f3 Entity count "e" will tell you how many mobs are in the direction you are facing.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it means anything significant, definitely not that there's a dungeon around.

I have noticed that I tend to hear it as I descend into darkness or reach the surface during the day, so I believe that there are triggers to improve the mood, just not ones that are related to dungeons (yet).

Answer (score 5):

I've heard it when entering a dark area when I'm caving before put torches up.  This has happened regularly enough to make me think it is a trigger for the scary music, but may be just a coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

The train-like noise means that you're near an unlit undiscovered cave system. One of the noises of which I'm not sure means that you're near a dungeon, but the only problem is that you can't tell whether to dig in front of you, behind you, up, down, left, or right.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell the music is mostly meaningless.  I have heard that it signifies morning has come but it doesn't always play then.  I think it's more there to just freak you out or get you inspired than it is to serve any mechanical purpose.

Comment: Now there's a game design idea; play sinister music snatches at random. "dun Dun DUUUN!"

Comment: I was under the impression that it meant a mob had spawned somewhere in the vicinity

Comment: @Keaanu If that's the case it would never play on peaceful.  Since it does play on peaceful, there goes that theory.

Comment: According to what I could understand from a [forum topic](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=40917), mobs spawn on every difficulty level, but they are removed right after spawning on Peaceful.