# When does Minecraft decide to start playing gameplay music?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've played mostly with Minecraft's music muted since Alpha, and have just recently started keeping it on while I play.

In the latest version (1.10), the subtle gameplay music seems to kick in ten or twenty minutes after starting the game and wandering around above ground. It will play for a while, then go away.

Is there any pattern to the gameplay music, or are there any special triggers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Minecraft's scary music mean?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8949/what-does-minecrafts-scary-music-mean)

Comment: Though I just dupe voted, it occurs to me that this is probably different, as the linked question asks about *cave sounds*, and this one appears to ask about the *music*.  (CC @yx.)

Comment: @yx.—I read through that question. It addresses the ambient sounds, not ambient music.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, first, there are two terms you're using here that may cause confusion. Ambience is the term used to describe the "cave noises" that play when near caves. I will assume that you are talking about the gameplay music, though, so here's that.

Until recently, I thought that is was completely random, but it actually isn't. A random track is selected at sunrise, sunset, noon, and midnight, though in some cases no music at all will be selected. This chooses completely randomly between the various Minecraft in-game music tracks.

Comment: Ambient music and ambient noise are both very standard terms. But I think that "ambiance" in Minecraft refers more often to the cave noises.

Comment: @DanR: True, but the wiki refers to them with these terms. He wasn't wrong, I was just clarifying.

Comment: That would be a good reason to stick to those terms! I also found your answer under the "trivia" section on the page. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I play Minecraft all day and I've noticed that a track plays at sunset and midnight.

Answer (score 1):

It triggers during parts of the day (sunset midnight day etc...) then there is ambient like when your wondering through caves and exploring the nether getting close to a dungeon etc... There is also some transition music but it does not come out often like when your walking through special biomes and such like planes forests etc... there are some mods that make it happen more often and others that just add more music to make it seem like it happens more often. If you are using the Xbox version then it is playing almost all the time.