# How to 'force' Minecraft music to play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have taken a look at these two answers but they do not mention a way to force the Minecraft music to play: [[1]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47491/when-does-minecraft-decide-to-start-playing-gameplay-music) [[2]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240731/why-doesnt-the-music-in-minecraft-play-all-the-time)

I was wondering if there is a way to 'force' music to play, whether this is achieved through datapacks, commands, or simply by walking to a specific area under specific conditions to make it happen.

Does anyone know if there is any way of doing this?

Comment: is there a particular song you want, or do you just want music to be playing?

Comment: @Millard It's the music that randomly plays when you're out and about. Like if I'm chilling at my house in the game, music only randomly seems to play occasionally (like when morning comes). This is the music that I'm wondering how to force

Comment: To add to this, one of the comments from the other answers, in case it helps, is: "Until recently, I thought that is was completely random, but it actually isn't. A random track is selected at sunrise, sunset, noon, and midnight, though in some cases no music at all will be selected. This chooses completely randomly between the various Minecraft in-game music tracks."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force Minecraft music to play with the `/playsound` command.

Syntax:

```
playsound <sound> <source> <targets> [<position>] [<volume>] [<pitch>] [<minVolume>]
```

For example:

```
/playsound minecraft:music.creative music @s ~ ~ ~ 999999
```

(The volume is not how loud the sound is, but how far from the source you can still hear it. Since you probably don't want the music to fade when you move away from the `position`, it is set to an extremely high number.)

---

Using Minecraft's autocomplete feature, if you type in:

```
/playsound minecraft:music.
```

...a list of options will appear, and you can select which one you like.